# Absorption wavelength of nickel (II)

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy, absorbance

One of my students is trying to study a nickel(II) solution, prepared from nickel(II) sulfate, which is green. In solution it is also green, thus I would expect it to absorb red light. Here is a test run in a colorimeter:

[image: Colorimeter data from nickel(II)]

with each signal corresponding to 430, 470, 565 and 635 nm, respectively. The absorption spectrum of nickel (II) sulfate is shown below:

[image: Nickel (II) Uv-vis data]

What I don't understand is why 470 nm shows the greatest absorbance in the colorimeter, if in the UV-vis spectrum it quite clearly shows it should absorb more at 635 nm?

Comment: Looks rather like max at 400 nm, not 470 nm. Be aware of difference between radiometric ( objective ) and photometric ( eye sensitivity aware ) parameters. Eyes are much more sensitive to some 650-720 nm than to 400 nm. Absorbance at region of low eye sensitivity is less significant, as its influence on subjective light attenuation is low.

Comment: What is the meaning of the absorbance measured versus the time ? The time !!! Does it change with the time ?

Comment: It doesn't really change with time, no.
@Poutnik, max is indeed at about 400nm, which is why I would expect the colorimeter to absorb more at 430m, not 470. The colorimeter spectrum shows a higher absorbance at 470nm.

Answer (score 1):

The spectrometer irradiates each wavelength alone so the green light is always transmitted, close to 100%T or zero A. The absorption bands are measured and are used analytically. The colorimeter passes the complete visual spectrum so what you see predominately are the wavelengths that are passed by the sample aka its color. This means that increasing concentrations of the material pass selectively more light of its color and the color becomes more intense. More green more nickel. The intense color means that the absorption bands, the light that you do not see, are relatively strong.  If you shine only green light on it in a darkened room All concentrations would look the same, possibly they would all look white since the transmission is 100% and our brain can interpret 100% as white.

A story. I was going to bleach a photograph using potassium dichromate, a bright orange solid. I weighed some out on a watch glass and went into the dark room placed the watch glass on the counter turned on the orange safelight and turned off the room lights and looked for the dichromate. It WASN'T there! There was a watch glass with a bright white chemical in it.  Quickly turned the room light on and there was the orange chemical. One must be very careful when working with selective frequency or monochromatic light sources such as Lasers. What you think you see may not be what is really there.